# libdvdread: unable to seek block nnnn

Tags: fedora

I am experiencing a very odd error on a couple of user machines which I am unable to root cause.

They are all running Fedora 30 and VLC 3.0.8.   The symptoms are the same.  VLC plays a DVD for 4:58 and then hangs.  Running in super verbose mode `vlc -vvv` show that libdvdread throws the exception `unable to seek block <nnnn>`.

I have searched the VLC forums and have not found anything related.  Has anyone seen this issue or know what might be the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up updating the kernel (minor rev) and now the error message is gone and VLC is working fine.